# Sony Internet TV Quality for Mid-High Range Build and XBOX 360

Tags: display, tv, hdtv, google-tv

I was wondering about [Sony's new Internet TVs](http://www.sonystyle.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/CategoryDisplay?catalogId=10551&storeId=10151&langId=-1&categoryId=8198552921644751998&XID=O:tv%20with%20google:corp_sitv10_gglsrch:sitbracont_goog_ad1#/Feature_DualView) with built-in Google TV functionality, and their performance when it comes to gaming with a mid-high end PC build, as well as a 360.

I'm not very knowledgable when it comes to Monitors and TVs as far as what I should look at in the specifications, so any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your xbox should have no problems with it. It's designed to connect to a TV after all. The gaming PC will work, but will require some adjustments. You'll need to turn off overscan compensation to prevent the video card from shrinking and black-bordering the output. You might also need to set the resolution manually.

Comment: OK, but as far as the quality and "performance" of this as a monitor, what do you think?  I'm looking into the 32" or 40" and it has a 60Hz refresh rate, which I heard isn't bad.